# Plotly Dash theme: LUX (Dark mode)

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I want to use the built-in bootswatch theme [LUX](https://bootswatch.com/lux/) but looks like only light mode is included in Dash i.e. when I use the below sample code, theme is applied in light mode. How can I have the dark mode instead? I don't care much about the ability to toggle between light and dark modes, just want to use this theme in the dark mode as the default and the only option. Thanks for helping.

```
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.LUX])
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it, just need to save a .js file in assets with this line:

```
document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-bs-theme', 'dark')
```

Source: https://hellodash.pythonanywhere.com/adding-themes/color-modes